# Как сделать сбор файлов в памяти?

Tags: c#

Подскажите как собирается файлы в памяти?
Насколько я понял, создаём метод который возвращает `byte[]`

```
public static byte[] Method(string filepath)
{
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
   {
     //... Тут какая-то отработка...
     return ms.ToArray();
   }
}
```

Что если мне нужно добавить каждый файл в папку ( в памяти) и после создать архив из памяти с этими файлами и папками.
Я так понял ещё можно работать напрямую через ZipStorer библиотеку?

Вообще просто хочу понять как реализовывается сбор данных в памяти с дополнительным сжатием или шифрованием данных и.т.д

Comment: я ничего не понял. Память в конечном виде - это набор битов, что хотите там, то и храните. Все будет так храниться, как вы организуете. Хотите- храните файлы в сжатом виде, хотите - в несжатом.

Comment: @tym32167, я просто в мыслях... думаю можно ли как-нибудь создать один класс с одним методом который вберёт в себя сбор данных любого типа, если такое возможно конечно.

Comment: Файл - это некая структура, у нее есть обычно дата создания, изменения, имя, размер, другие атрибуты. А массив байт - это массив байт. Ваш код, как хотите, так и храните.

Comment: Папка - это набор (коллекция) файлов. В памяти можете использовать любую подходящую коллекцию, например, List.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, теория это очень прекрасно, но хотелось так же немного практичного кода, чтобы понимать как это в принципе реализовывается...

Comment: Ваш метод возвращает массив байтов: `byte[]`. Вероятно, это представляет один файл. Значит, папку будет представлять коллекция таких массивов: `List<byte[]>`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, понял. А как сама папка добавляется в список? Ну я имею ввиду как это в коде будет выглядеть ?

Comment: В список - никак, он же список, а не дерево.